# Как оформить следующие цитаты?

Tags: пунктуация, прямая-речь, цитата

Вывести на индустриальные орбиты службы людям свои рекордные компоненты механизмов я так и не могу. Как в обессилевшей послевоенной России, так и в обезумевшей реформируемой и отброшенной перестроенной, заставившей сказать по-лермонтовски «Прощай, умытая Россия» или как Джульетто Пьеза «Прощай, Россия», так и на американском самодовольном материке.

Comment: Артем, спасибо, исправила...

Answer (score 1):

Может быть, так? Как в обессилевшей послевоенной России, так и в обезумевшей реформируемой и отброшенной перестроеЧной России, заставившей, ПЕРЕФРАЗИРОВАВ ЛЕРМОНТОВА, сказать «Прощай, умытая Россия», или, как Джульетто Кьеза, СКАЗАТЬ ПРОСТО «Прощай, Россия», так и на американском самодовольном материке (континенте).
 Я думаю, что цитаты (в первом случае это перефразированная строка стихотворения - обычная прямая речь, а во  втором  - название произведения) у Вас, Алёнка , оформлены правильно.